# How to apply newly installed theme in 14.04?

Tags: edubuntu

I've installed human-theme_0.39.2_all.deb but it doesn't seem in appearance just default themes are there.

How I can apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply themes in Unity desktop other than Ambiance and Radiance you need to install the Unity Tweak Tool.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Comment: Which version of unity tweek tool for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS . I've tried GNOME tweek tool.deb it said Dependency is not satisfiable: gnome-shell-common(=>3.4 )

Answer (score 1):

Probably there may be a dependancy problem. You can overcome it by installing through main repo.

Human-theme 0.39.2 is in [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=human-theme&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all).

You can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install human-theme
```

---

Edit:

Update the system before install:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: That command doesn't work saying E: Unable to locate package human-theme

Comment: Run apt-get update and try again and if neccesary edit your question to show the output of the install command.